# Test numbers between 2 values ​successively in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

"*We can apply this algorithm without going through a table: an integer n is prime if **d varying from 2
at
√n**
n checks the condition:
As long as it is not divisible by d, we increment the value of d. If n is divisible by d then n
is not first. And of course, if n is not divisible by any of the values ​​taken by d, then n
is prime.*"

My question is How I can say in python that d is varying from 2 at √n ? range ? randint ? but randint is random and range didn't work with math.sqrt(n)

And what **√n** is suposed to mean like if I chose 7 as number n and 2 as d then it's stupid because √7 is 2.64575131106 so I just test the algorithm between 2 and 2.64575131106...

Edit after answers:

When I return True nothing is displayed

[image: terminal results]
[image: code]

Comment: It's not stupid. Indeed, to test whether 7 is prime, you only need to test that 7 is not divisible by 2.

Comment: The thing is, you want to test whether there exists two numbers a,b with 2 <= a < n and 2 <= b < n such that `n == a * b`. But such an equality is only possibly if a <= sqrt(n) and b >= sqrt(n) (or vice-versa). Indeed, if they were both smaller or both larger than sqrt(n), then their product would be smaller or larger than n. So, you only need to test with 2 <= a < sqrt(n). The fact that sqrt(n) is not an integer not important.

Comment: Note that limiting the search to between 2 and sqrt(n) is an optimization. If you search a little too much, for instance if you search for all divisors `d` between 2 and sqrt(n)+1, or for all divisors `d` between 2 and n-1, it's correct too. Just make sure you don't include 1 or `n` in the possible divisors.

Answer (score 1):

### Using `math.sqrt` and rounding up

You can round `sqrt(n)` up to an integer, using `int(sqrt(n) + 0.5)`.

```py
from math import sqrt

def is_prime(n):
    for d in range(2, int(sqrt(n) + 0.5)):
        if n % d == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Or alternatively, using `all` or `any`:

```py
from math import sqrt

def is_prime(n):
    return all(n % d > 0 for d in range(2, int(sqrt(n) + 0.5)))
```

### Using `math.isqrt`

In python>=3.8, there is a function called `isqrt` in the `math` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isqrt

It returns the largest integer `a` such that `a*a <= n`. This is exactly what we want.

```py
from math import isqrt

def is_prime(n):
    for d in range(2, isqrt(n)+1):
        if n % d == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Or alternatively, using `all` or `any`:

```py
from math import isqrt

def is_prime(n):
    return all(n % d > 0 for d in range(2, isqrt(n) + 1))
```

### Not using `sqrt` at all

Or alternatively, if you don't want to use `math.sqrt` at all:

```py
def is_prime(n):
    d = 2
    while d * d <= n:
        if n % d == 0:
            return False
        d += 1
    return True
```

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try this

Comment: I tested the first thing with sqrt(n) + 0.5 and when It's True my terminal won't display it, it display only when it's False

Comment: @swken999 Are you sure you included the `return True` at the end?

Comment: Yes it works only when I do print(True)

Comment: What? It's a function. Don't use `print`. Use `return`.